# Cells to automatically format entries as email hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, automation

Excel experts -

I am dealing with a spreadsheet that has multiple macros running through it and has been extremely useful, however it does have one process that I would like to see if it is possible to automate, and so far my attempts and research has come up with nada.

I have a userform entering in a client's email address directly into the next row of Sheet1 that is empty, and the email is in column H2:H3000.  There are several other tasks that Column H is already programmed to do, for instance, when the email is an active hyperlink and the user selects it, it generates an e-mail message through Outlook and within column K, anytime a hyperlink is selected, it records the date and time of the action, as well as the userID of who made the action.  The main problem with this current set-up is that, a user has to go through each cell in column H and double-click the email and click outside of it in order to activate the hyperlink.  Is there a way that this can be automated to any enter within Column H?

Thanks!

Comment: Current code:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range (“H3:H1500”)) Is Nothing Then
Range.Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= (hyperlink value which is equal to the text entry) TextToDisplay:=(Text Entry)

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give more specific instructions without seeing your code, but one option may be to add the link as a Hyperlink rather than straight text.  See the example below and let me know if it helps.

`ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("H1"), Me.TextBox1.Value`

Per request, the below code can be used in the `Worksheet` module to change a text entry to a link when the `Worksheet_Change` event fires.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H3:H1500")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Target, Address:=Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am guessing you are suggesting adding that line to the userform itself?  I am trying to figure out if it would be better to place within the Worksheet as a Private Sub to identify changes to the column range and automatically convert text to hyperlinks that way, but the object defining is not liking any of the syntax...Thoughts?

Comment: The choice of location is ultimately yours, based on expected usage. I personally prefer to control activity directly from the `userform`, but this doesn't control changes directly to the worksheet. I created a simulated environment to test, and adding a value to the spreadsheet from a userform does NOT raise the `worksheet_change` event.  I will edit my answer demonstrating how to properly change text to a link using the worksheet change event for your reference